# Convert Int32 to CultureInfo PowerShell vs C#

Tags: c#, powershell, casting

In PowerShell I can use this syntax:

```
PS C:\> [globalization.cultureinfo]1049

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1049             ru-RU            Russian (Russia)


PS C:\> [globalization.cultureinfo]1033

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1033             en-US            English (United States)


PS C:\> [globalization.cultureinfo]1080

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1080             fo-FO            Faroese (Faroe Islands)
```

But I cannot achieve same cast with C#:

```
var eng = (CultureInfo)1033;
```

Gives compile-time error:

> Error CS0030  Cannot convert type 'int' to
>   'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'

How does it works in PowerShell and how to do same with C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell implicitly calls the [CultureInfo(Int32) constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/205h6kwc(v=vs.110).aspx), i.e. `new CultureInfo(1049)`.

PowerShell's conversion rules are documented [on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2013/06/11/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/). In your case, rule 5 applies:

> 5. **Constructor conversion.** If the target type defines a constructor that takes your input, use that.

Proof:

```
PS> Trace-Command TypeConversion { [Globalization.CultureInfo]1049 | Out-Null } -PSHost
DEBUG: TypeConversion Information: 0 : Constructor result: "ru-RU".
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably done by some PowerShell internals. Like you can cast a string to `[xml]`. This probably isn't possible by casting in C#. However,  use the static `GetCultureInfo` method which takes an integer:

```
var eng = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1033)
```

Comment: I know this. My question is how works this cast in powershell

Comment: Thought you just want to get an answer how to do it. I updated my answer.